How could i add username field in WooCommerce
I don't know how to add username field in registration page.
There is no settings about this also.
Used to be there is a setting about adding a username field but not now how could i add username field in woocommerce registration i already tried to code but it doesn't work.
I tried to add the code like this;
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'custom_woocommerce_register_username' );
function custom_woocommerce_register_username() {
    ?>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_username"><?php _e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['username'] ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <?php
} 
// Kullanıcı adı alanının zorunlu olmasını sağlama
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_errors', 'custom_woocommerce_registration_errors_username', 10, 3 );
function custom_woocommerce_registration_errors_username( $errors, $username, $email ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['username'] ) && empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'username_error', __( 'Username is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    return $errors;
}

// Kayıt sırasında kullanıcı adını kaydetme
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'custom_save_registration_fields_username' );
function custom_save_registration_fields_username( $customer_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['username'] ) ) {
        wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $customer_id, 'user_login' => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['username'] ) ) );
    }
} 


// Add Username Field to Registration Form
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'custom_woocommerce_register_username' );
function custom_woocommerce_register_username() {
    ?>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_username"><?php _e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" />
    </p>
    <?php
}

// Validate Username Field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_errors', 'custom_woocommerce_registration_errors_username', 10, 3 );
function custom_woocommerce_registration_errors_username( $errors, $username, $email ) {
    if ( empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'username_error', __( 'Username is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );
    } elseif ( username_exists( $_POST['username'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'username_error', __( 'This username is already taken. Please choose another one.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    return $errors;
}

// Save Username Field
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'custom_save_registration_fields_username' );
function custom_save_registration_fields_username( $customer_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['username'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) {
        wp_update_user( array(
            'ID'         => $customer_id,
            'user_login' => sanitize_user( $_POST['username'] ),
        ) );
    }
}

// Prevent Auto-Generation of Username from Email
add_filter( 'woocommerce_new_customer_data', 'custom_override_auto_generated_username', 10, 1 );
function custom_override_auto_generated_username( $data ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['username'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) {
        $data['user_login'] = sanitize_user( $_POST['username'] );
    }
    return $data;
}

